# How can I display a colon in an output for displaying times?

Tags: python, string, integer, output

The output should display time in this format: 8:00 a.m.

```
def save_time():
     cse_info = {}
     again = 'Y'     
     while again.lower() == 'y':

             cse_num = int(input('Enter course number:'))
             cse_time = int(input('Enter course meeting time:'))

             cse_info['CS' + str(cse_num)] = str(cse_time) + ' a.m.'         
             again = input('Do you want to enter another course?')        
     print(cse_info)

save_time()
```

Comment: What input are you expecting fot `cse_time`? Something like "0833"?

Comment: trying to create an input that takes a number and display this format: 8:00

Comment: Fix your indentation first, poorly indented questions cannot be answered

Comment: Should all numbers produce `8:00`? What if I enter `850`?

Comment: @vishes_shell how are you sure that's the correct indentation that goes under the while loop? Did the OP say that? Don't edit questions if you're not 100% sure. The next three lines also might go under the while loop. Wait for OP

Comment: @abccd i've looked in edit history and i've seen that indentation, and i thought that was the original one... Should've looked little bit lower. My bad, i agree. I know the rules, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you  need a way to exit your while loop... It should otherwise work.

```
def save_time():

         cse_info = {}
         again = 'Y'

         while again.lower() == 'y':

             cse_num = int(input('Enter course number:'))
             cse_time = int(input('Enter course meeting time:'))
             break # maybe you want to check for an exit condition?

         cse_info['CS' + str(cse_num)] = str(cse_time) + ' a.m.'

         again = input('Do you want to enter another course?')

         print(cse_info)


save_time()
```

I'll do it for you this time, but this is not a homework site.

```
def save_time():
         cse_info = {}
         while True:
             cse_num = int(input('Enter course number:'))
             cse_time = int(input('Enter course meeting time:'))
             cse_info['CS' + str(cse_num)] = str(cse_time) + ' a.m.'
             again = input('Do you want to enter another course? (1=yes 2=no')
             if not again: break

         print(cse_info)

save_time()
```

Comment: It looks like poor indentation, the OP probably indented everything under the while loop, so it is possible to exit the while loop because of the changing `again` variable. This is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

If the input for `cse_time` is in the format of "0800" being "8:00", then you can replace `str(cse_time) + ' a.m.'` with `str(cse_time)[:2]+":"+str(cse_time)[2:] + ' a.m.'` to add in a semicolon. Or you could have `cse_time` be a string so the input can be `8:00`.